# Loading saved Tensorflow model in Java

Tags: java, python, linux, windows, tensorflow

I have developed a Tensorflow model with python in Linux based on the tutorial here: "http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/training-convolutional-neural-network-for-image-classification/". I trained and saved the model using "tf.train.Saver". I am able to deploy the model in Linux environment and perform prediction successfully. Now I need to be able to load this saved model in JAVA on WINDOWS. Through extensive research online I have read that it does not work with "tf.train.Saver" and I have to change my code to use "Serving" to be able to load a saved TF model in java! Therefore, I followed the tutorial here:
"https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model.py
" and changed my code. However, I have an error with "tf.FixedLenFeature" where it is asking me to use "FixedLenSequenceFeature". Here is the complete error message:

*"ValueError: First dimension of shape for feature x unknown. Consider using FixedLenSequenceFeature."*

which is happening here:

```
feature_configs = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None, img_size,img_size,num_channels], dtype=tf.float32),}
```

I am not sure this is the right path to go since I have batch of images of size [batchsize*128*128*3] and should not be using the sequence feature! It would be great if someone could clear this out for me and answer these questions:

1- Do I have to change my code from "tf.train.Saver" to "serving" to be able to load the saved model and deploy it in JAVA?

2- If the answer to the above question is yes, how can I feed the data correctly and solve the aforementioned ERROR?

3- Is there any example of how to DEPLOY the model that was saved using "serving"?

Here is my training code that throws the error:

```
import dataset
import tensorflow as tf
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import os


#Adding Seed so that random initialization is consistent
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2)

batch_size = 32

#Prepare input data
classes = ['class1','class2','class3']
num_classes = len(classes)

# 20% of the data will automatically be used for validation
validation_size = 0.2
img_size = 128
num_channels = 3
train_path='/home/user1/Downloads/Expression/Augmented/Data/Train'
# We shall load all the training and validation images and labels into memory using openCV and use that during training
data = dataset.read_train_sets(train_path, img_size, classes, validation_size=validation_size)

print("Complete reading input data. Will Now print a snippet of it")
print("Number of files in Training-set:\t\t{}".format(len(data.train.labels)))
print("Number of files in Validation-set:\t{}".format(len(data.valid.labels)))

session = tf.Session()
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example')
feature_configs = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[None, img_size,img_size,num_channels], dtype=tf.float32),}
tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)
x = tf.identity(tf_example['x'], name='x')  # use tf.identity() to assign name

# x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, img_size,img_size,num_channels], name='x')

## labels
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='y_true')
y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y_true, dimension=1)

##Network graph params
filter_size_conv1 = 3 
num_filters_conv1 = 32

filter_size_conv2 = 3
num_filters_conv2 = 32

filter_size_conv3 = 3
num_filters_conv3 = 64

fc_layer_size = 128

def create_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))

def create_biases(size):
    return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[size]))


def create_convolutional_layer(input,
               num_input_channels, 
               conv_filter_size,        
               num_filters):  

    ## We shall define the weights that will be trained using create_weights function.
    weights = create_weights(shape=[conv_filter_size, conv_filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters])
    ## We create biases using the create_biases function. These are also trained.
    biases = create_biases(num_filters)

    ## Creating the convolutional layer
    layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input,
                     filter=weights,
                     strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                     padding='SAME')

    layer += biases

    ## We shall be using max-pooling.  
    layer = tf.nn.max_pool(value=layer,
                            ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                            strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                            padding='SAME')
    ## Output of pooling is fed to Relu which is the activation function for us.
    layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

    return layer



def create_flatten_layer(layer):
    #We know that the shape of the layer will be [batch_size img_size img_size num_channels] 
    # But let's get it from the previous layer.
    layer_shape = layer.get_shape()

    ## Number of features will be img_height * img_width* num_channels. But we shall calculate it in place of hard-coding it.
    num_features = layer_shape[1:4].num_elements()

    ## Now, we Flatten the layer so we shall have to reshape to num_features
    layer = tf.reshape(layer, [-1, num_features])

    return layer


def create_fc_layer(input,          
             num_inputs,    
             num_outputs,
             use_relu=True):

    #Let's define trainable weights and biases.
    weights = create_weights(shape=[num_inputs, num_outputs])
    biases = create_biases(num_outputs)

    # Fully connected layer takes input x and produces wx+b.Since, these are matrices, we use matmul function in Tensorflow
    layer = tf.matmul(input, weights) + biases
    if use_relu:
        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

    return layer


layer_conv1 = create_convolutional_layer(input=x,
               num_input_channels=num_channels,
               conv_filter_size=filter_size_conv1,
               num_filters=num_filters_conv1)
layer_conv2 = create_convolutional_layer(input=layer_conv1,
               num_input_channels=num_filters_conv1,
               conv_filter_size=filter_size_conv2,
               num_filters=num_filters_conv2)

layer_conv3= create_convolutional_layer(input=layer_conv2,
               num_input_channels=num_filters_conv2,
               conv_filter_size=filter_size_conv3,
               num_filters=num_filters_conv3)

layer_flat = create_flatten_layer(layer_conv3)

layer_fc1 = create_fc_layer(input=layer_flat,
                     num_inputs=layer_flat.get_shape()[1:4].num_elements(),
                     num_outputs=fc_layer_size,
                     use_relu=True)

layer_fc2 = create_fc_layer(input=layer_fc1,
                     num_inputs=fc_layer_size,
                     num_outputs=num_classes,
                     use_relu=False) 

y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(layer_fc2,name='y_pred')

y_pred_cls = tf.argmax(y_pred, dimension=1)

values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(y_pred, 3)
table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_to_string_table_from_tensor(
      tf.constant([str(i) for i in xrange(3)]))
prediction_classes = table.lookup(tf.to_int64(indices))


session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=layer_fc2,
                                                    labels=y_true)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(cost)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(y_pred_cls, y_true_cls)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 


def show_progress(epoch, feed_dict_train, feed_dict_validate, val_loss):
    acc = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)
    val_acc = session.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict_validate)
    msg = "Training Epoch {0} --- Training Accuracy: {1:>6.1%}, Validation Accuracy: {2:>6.1%},  Validation Loss: {3:.3f}"
    print(msg.format(epoch + 1, acc, val_acc, val_loss))

total_iterations = 0

# saver = tf.train.Saver()
def train(num_iteration):
    global total_iterations

    for i in range(total_iterations,
                   total_iterations + num_iteration):

        x_batch, y_true_batch, _, cls_batch = data.train.next_batch(batch_size)
        x_valid_batch, y_valid_batch, _, valid_cls_batch = data.valid.next_batch(batch_size)


        feed_dict_tr = {x: x_batch,
                           y_true: y_true_batch}
        feed_dict_val = {x: x_valid_batch,
                              y_true: y_valid_batch}

        session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_tr)

        if i % int(data.train.num_examples/batch_size) == 0: 
            print(i)
            val_loss = session.run(cost, feed_dict=feed_dict_val)
            epoch = int(i / int(data.train.num_examples/batch_size))    

            show_progress(epoch, feed_dict_tr, feed_dict_val, val_loss)
            print("Saving the model Now!")
            # saver.save(session, save_path_full, global_step=i) 


    total_iterations += num_iteration

train(num_iteration=10000)#3000


# Export model
# WARNING(break-tutorial-inline-code): The following code snippet is
# in-lined in tutorials, please update tutorial documents accordingly
# whenever code changes.
export_path_base = './SavedModel/'
export_path = os.path.join(
  tf.compat.as_bytes(export_path_base),
  tf.compat.as_bytes(str(1)))
print 'Exporting trained model to', export_path
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

# Build the signature_def_map.
classification_inputs = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(
  serialized_tf_example)
classification_outputs_classes = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(
  prediction_classes)
classification_outputs_scores = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(values)

classification_signature = (
  tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
      inputs={
          tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS:
              classification_inputs
      },
      outputs={
          tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES:
              classification_outputs_classes,
          tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_SCORES:
              classification_outputs_scores
      },
      method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME))

tensor_info_x = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(x)
tensor_info_y = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(y_pred)

prediction_signature = (
  tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
      inputs={'images': tensor_info_x},
      outputs={'scores': tensor_info_y},
      method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
  sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
  signature_def_map={
      'predict_images':
          prediction_signature,
      tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
          classification_signature,
  },
  legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)

builder.save()

print 'Done exporting!'
```